# How to create a function that sorts a numeric array and be able swap arrays on the fly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code

```
        var content = [ 409, 879, 483, 465, 907, 154, 838, 847 ]//the array

        var result = content.sort( function( a, b ){ return a - b } )//This works

        alert( result )//works. But I want to be able to easily swap out arrays like below

        function order( ary )//this function returns undefined, why?
        {
            ary.sort( function( a, b ){ return a - b } )//order numbers from least to greatest;
        }

        var result = order( content );

        alert( result )//returns undefined
```

Not sure why my order function returns undefined, yet outside of a function that code works? I would like to allow the order function to accept any array when called. Thanks and yes I'm newbie.

Comment: The function does not return anything.

Comment: @aduch `Array.prototype.sort` does return sorted array as well as sorts original array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return result

```
function order( ary )
{
    return ary.sort( function( a, b ){ return a - b } )//order numbers from least to greatest;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/?js,console